# Applying the action from ifPresentOrElse() on Every element of the stream

Tags: java, java-stream

In my Java application I'm using the following stream:

```java
columns.stream()
    .map(columnEncryptors::get)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresentOrElse(columnEncryptor -> 
        columnEncryptor.encrypt(bankTransaction),
        () -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException("No encryptor"); }
    );
```

The `columns` list met contains `9` strings, the code above is performing the action only for the first one, but not the other `8`.

How can change the code fire the same action for every element in the `columns` list?

Comment: "Is there a operation that can do this?" <- Can do **what**? What is "this" in this context? You only told us that you don't want the behavior of findFirst, but didn't tell us what you actually want.

Comment: I am searching for an operation that goes through all of the 9 strings, not only the first one.

Comment: …and returns _what_?

Comment: and do the following operation on all 9:

`
`(columnEncryptor -> columnEncryptor.encrypt(bankTransaction), () -> {throw new IllegalArgumentException("No encryptor");})`

Comment: *I am searching for an operation that goes through all of the 9 strings, not only the first one* - you need to fire the action for every element?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: @DennisvanPutten, use `Stream.map` or `Stream.forEach` instead of `Stream.findFirst().ifPresentOrElse` if I understood you correctly.

Comment: First of all, you should understand what your original code does. The statement `throw new IllegalArgumentException("No encryptor");` will be executed only when `columns` is empty, which has nothing to do with the availability of encryptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the action on every element you don't need `findFirst`, deal with `Optional` and there's no need to create a stream at all.

```
columns.forEach(column -> {
    ColumnEncryptor encryptor = columnEncryptors.get(column);
    if (encryptor != null) columnEncryptor.encrypt(bankTransaction)
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("No encryptor");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are only able to process first one is because of the `.findFirst`. You can try using `.forEach` instead then all the elements in the stream will be processed:

```java
columns.stream()
  .map(columnEncryptors::get)
  .forEach((columnEncryptor) -> {
    <LOGIC FOR EACH ELEMENT> 
  })
```

Comment: It will not compile.

Comment: Agree correcting `forEach` with lambda expression to check conditional

Comment: bebcause of the forEach()

Comment: How about now @AlexanderIvanchenko

Comment: @PseudoAj Now it better but your stream performs actions via side effects which isn't encouraged by the [*API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects). And usage of stream doesn't seem to give a lot of convince here, since consumer passed to the `forEach()` would be a multiline lambda expression doe to the need to represent the conditional logic.